# Symfony Entity Form em usage

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building the following form in Symfony2

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setAction('')
            ->add('username','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('password','password',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('title','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('firstName','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('surname','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('school','entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Schools',
                'choices' => $sch->mySchool(),
                'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(), 
                'property'=>'title', 
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')
                )
            )
            ->add('role','entity',array('class'=>'AppBundle:UserRoles','property'=>'description','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('save','submit',array('label'=>'Save','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')))
            ->getForm();
```

and the issue is with the following line

```
'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(),
```

having read up on this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html I'm trying to use the 'Using Choices' way of doing things, my form displays and return all schools instead of just the one school my method actually returns.

I've had a look around and can't find an example of using the 'em' value, has anybody used this method before?

I'm reluctant to go down the 'query_builder' route as I want to be able to use the mySchool() method in other areas of the application I'm building.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `em` option is just there if you specifically want to use another entity manager instance. Most applications only have one entity manager, so you rarely see this used.

That being said, if you're providing the choices directly, then the EntityType doesn't need to know which entity manager to use at all, so I'd omit it - it's likely that explicitly including it is overriding your `choices`

Comment: Sorry should've said, not including the 'em' line returns the same results I found this which may or may not be confusing the issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/618

For the time being I may just use the query_bulder method and see what implications this has moving forward

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are passing a "School" object for the "choices".
The "choices" option should be an array or be an instanceof \Traversable. When it's none of them it just ignores the option and fallback to the default behaviour > loads all objects from DB

Try the following:

```
'choices' => array($sch->mySchool()),
```